# How to render an object containing functions in code mirror (angular) properly

Tags: codemirror, ngx-codemirror

I need to render in **code mirror** ( a plugin to display code snippets in the frontend ) an object containing functions, my object looks like:

```
{
lang:"en",

func1: function(e){
            console.log(e);
       },
    

func2: function(f){
           alert(f);
     }

 }
```

I've tried using JSON.stringify with a replace, like:

```
JSON.stringify(finalGlobalConfigObj, function(key, value) {
                if (typeof value === "function") {
                  return "/Function(" + value.toString() + ")/";
                }
                return value;
              }, 4);
```

However, the rendering is not great because it just render the content as a String.

How can I render correctly my object that is containing functions?

I'm using code mirror inside an angular application.

Comment: If is there any alternative to code mirror is fine also

Comment: did you use the javascript language packs in codemirror? can we see how you are using codemirror?